# Right convention to use in Laravel database/model setup for relationships that needs different column's?

Tags: database, laravel, model, laravel-8

Okay let me explain what I want

I should have multiple "users" (ID, name, email ...), and each user should have 1 of multiple "account_types" (ID, name).

This seems pretty simple to setup, but here comes the tricky part.

Each "account_type" should have different info's and I then think the right way is to create a new table for each "account_type" with the columns needed for each type but I am not sure

Let me explain what I want with this example:

```
Account types:  
ID: 1, Name: Private user 
ID: 2, Name: Company user 
.... More to be added ....
```

The info needed for a Private users should be:

```
First name, Last name
```

But for the company users it should be:

```
Company name, Company identification number
```

I could of course just store this info within the users table, making them nullable, and just output the info needed according to what "account_type" it is, but that seems wrong as the nullable options will grow and grow as more "account_types" is added. Furthermore I need to hardcode what info I need based on the "account type" and I dont think that is the right convention to use here?

How should I setup this in Laravel? - What is the right convention here? - And if I am right about creating a new table for each "account_type", how would I make it to use (Do i need to create a Model for each table, and how do I tell Laravel to use the correct model, when making this to use)?

EDIT

After reading the comment from Anurat (and thank you for leading me in the right direction), I now know that the right way is to create a table for each account type, and then a model for each table, then I can use polymorphic relationships, but I am still unsecure on how it works

I have created the following migrations (And each migration has a model):

```
    Schema::create('account_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('private_account_infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('firm_account_infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('cvr');
        $table->string('company_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('account_type')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->morphs('fillable');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here I have sat the $table->morphs on the users table, but is that right? - The user either has info in firm_account_infos or private_account_infos so thats why I placed in the users table, but when I think about it, it should be "account_types" there desides if the user can have info in firm_account_infos or private_account_infos, so what changes do I need to take in my migrations to make it right?

Comment: create a table for each account type, create a model for each table and use polymorphic relationship with other tables https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: Thank you for the help!, but still I do not quite understand it. I have updated my question, could you kindly elaborate on what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is you don't need `account_types` table because we already split different type of accounts into tables i.e. privates and firms table. All records in privates will have the same account_type and the same for all records in firms.

Then you can have a one to one polymorphic relationship with `users` table.

```
 privates ----|
              |----- users
 firms -------|
```

And you will need to add to users table schema

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('userable_id');
    $table->string('userable_type');
});
```

Then you create a relationship in users, privates and firms.

```
// User model

public function userable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

// Private, Firm model

public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'userable');
}
```

When you want to retrieve the relevant model, you can

```
$user->userable;  // either private or firm

$private->user;
$firm->user;
```

Comment: Okay now it make sense, but what I didn't include in my question is that each account_type should also have multiple purposes. Ex. Private users have "buyer" and "seller" as purposes, and firms have "0-5", "5-10", "10-20", and finally "20+". How can i make this purposes table belongs to each "account_type", when removing that table?

Comment: @MichaelJorgensenDK I still don't understand those purposes. But you can still add account_type table which will have a normal one to many relationship with privates and firms table.

Comment: Can I make the "userable_type" come from another table (account_types), and only store the "userable_id" and "account_type_id" in the users table. Then "account_type_id.userable_type" should point to whatever table it belongs to?

Comment: yes, if your database design looks like the image, you can do that, but be sure to read the manual https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships